# Activity Monitor's Process Name connection to each software

Tags: memory, activity-monitor

I have Activity Monitor open to check how much memory is being used, and the main part I usually check is the bottom where it mentions how many GBs have been used. However, with the ability to stop it, I would now like to know what each Process Name belongs to and how it would affect it if I stopped it.

[image: Activity Monitor's Memory panel]

Some of them are easy to tell, such as one's with the Process Name being called "Google Chrome" which would have me come to the conclusion that if I stop it while I have it running, it will exit out of it. In other cases, however, it is very difficult to see what it is linked to and whether it would affect anything I have open at the moment. I have previously done one after some research: It was toward Core Sync for Adobe Creative Cloud, but without the research or Creative Cloud icon I would not have known what it would have affected.

This is what I mean when I say "stop": [image: The button that is called "stop"]

Is there a solution for how to find what each one of these Process Names is sourced with without having to do research for every one of them? Or, the overall question is how can I get enough information on each Process Name to find out things such as what software it is part of or what may happen if I hit "stop"?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. When you say "... with the ability to stop it ..." what do you mean? There can also be many Google Chrome Helper processes active, depending on the number of open tabs, running extensions, etc. If you click on the Process Name header, it will list all the processes in alphabetical order. This may help show you how some apps may have several processes running simultaneously. I see at least 2 Discord processes, 4 Google processes, etc. Note: if you kill the "Google Chrome" process, that will kill the entire Google Chrome process and subprocesses.

Comment: @IconDaemon I have edited the question to include what I mean by "stop". I'm asking if there is a solution for how to find what each one of them is linked to. I don't have any Adobe's open but I know the reason why Core Sync is still running (Cloud drive + updates). I'm just unsure about others such as "WindowServer".

Comment: WindowServer is your login session.  If you kill it, you will be returned to the login prompt.

Comment: You can click on the „i“ icon to see details about the selected process. It won’t tell you whether it can be killed/stopped without negative consequences though.

Comment: If you view by 'All Processes, Hierarchically', you'll see what belongs to what, but it still won't help knowing precisely which you can safely kill. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXvP8.png

Comment: As the question seems to ask two things simultaneously: Is this more about identifying the purpose of various processes in the system, or about how to kill processes in Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "I would now like to know what each Process Name is connected to", but you can find out more about each process using Terminal and the `ps` command.

For example, the command `ps -A` will list ALL processes with 1) their PID (process ID) as in Activity Monitor, and b) the command which started the process (in most cases, each apps file location and name).

So now you know the location of the command which started each process. Seems like a good first interpretation of what it is "connected to".

You can reduce the output of `ps -A` by combining with `grep`. For example: `ps -A | grep -i safari` will list all the processes related to Safari.

Activity Monitor is designed to keep things fairly simple; anything else will be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

> I would now like to know what each Process Name belongs to and **how it
> would affect it if I stopped it**.

I have over 600 processes running currently. The vast majority are part of the OS, and should not be stopped.

I would not recommend stopping any processes without good reason, e.g. stopped responding, or using a frightening amount of RAM or CPU. It's difficult to know what effects there will be from quitting processes that need to be running, but there can only be disadvantages.

Your memory usage is still 'in the green', and nothing to worry about. macOS will try to use as MUCH memory as it can. I'd just let the OS get on with the memory management, and you can get on with your work.

If you're concerned about memory usage, you could always stop using Chrome entirely, for a more efficient browser. ;-)